# Let Team foundation server show errors in a banner or a pop up

Tags: c#, dll, plugins, tfs

I'm writing an extension for TFS and I would like to show the user a pop up when something has failed.

Is this possible? I know a DLL for TFS cannot generate a form, but is there any other possible way?

I couldn't find anything about this on the internet.

I'm running TFS 2012

Answer (score 0):

Instead of TFS extension, you can set alerts for your project. As changes occur to work items, code reviews, source control files, and builds, you can receive email notifications for alerts that you define.

[image]

More information, check: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181334(v=vs.110).aspx